# how to transfer values from html form to Django admin?

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

I made one html form in which auto suggestion option also in city field. I want to know that how transfer the values of html form to django admin.

till now i made a model of form where fields like name,city,phone number,sex which register in admin.py. by this i am not able to register directly by django admin.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking? Are you wondering if you can get a HTML form to register in the django admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your html form, you have to create your function in views.py. 
In this file, you have to write the code which is going to receive the data you send from the html form.

Read the docs : [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/)

You probably have a html form like the following :

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    <label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
    <input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name" value="{{ current_name }}">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

You can create a form in forms.py :

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

Your function can look like this (in views.py)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
# if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
if request.method == 'POST':
    # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
    form = NameForm(request.POST)
    # check whether it's valid:
    if form.is_valid():
        # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
        # ...
        # redirect to a new URL:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

# if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
else:
    form = NameForm()

return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```